# data uri usage with color at the same time

Tags: css, data-uri

I was wondering if there is a way how to have a background with data uri and color at the same time. originally, I have background like this...

```
background:#222 url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==');
```

and I want to have my data url image with the css color above `#222`

is that possible?

**Update:** **I apologize for everyone controbuted to answering this question. I made a little mistake not replacing the data-uri code instead of the image path**

Thanks

Comment: A data URI is no different from any other URI, so I don't see why not.

Comment: with comma separated you can add different values background: url('images/arrow.png'), #222;

Comment: did you even test your code? your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use color + url, just write it in correct order :

> When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:
>
> background-color background-image background-repeat
>   background-attachment background-position It does not matter if one of
>   the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present
>   are in this order.

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3ba40qhs/)**

Css :

```
.bgnd{
    width:100%; 
    height:100px; 
    background: #ccc url("https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png");
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="bgnd"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different background properties:

```
background-color: #222;
background-image: url('images/arrow.png');
```

see further information here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: How can this improve the current posted code by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

you can define in your css background property with comma separated values.

```
  background: url('images/arrow.png'), #222;
```